# Pointers, How does this code work?

Tags: pointers

int j = 10;

```
void f() { 
    int *i; 
    i = &j;
    *i = 7;
    i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    *i = j; 
    j = j + 5; 
    printf("%d %d", *i, j);
}
```

Write down the two values that the function f will output

I am not able to fully understand how pointers work

So this is my interpretation of the code

```
 int j = 10;
```

J is assigned to value 10 in memory and has a address lets say 200

```
  int *i;
```

declaring a pointer

```
   i = &j;
```

i value is now 200

```
  *i = 7
```

value of *i  is 7

```
  i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int))
```

do not really understand what the above code is doing, but I think it assigns the variable i to the size of integer in array?

```
  *i = j
```

Does *i point to address of j or the value of j

```
   j = j + 5
```

the value of j (which I don't know what is) + 5

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend either reading a good C book or looking for a tutorial online to get some basics right.

```
int *i;
i = &j;
```

This makes pointer variable `i` to point to the same memory region where variable `j` resides (so your guess is right).

```
*i = 7;
```

Now, the location pointed to by `i` is updated to read 7. So, `j` is no longer 10, it's now 7 as `*i` and `j` are the same value.

```
i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Now, you allocated new piece of heap memory sufficient to hold a single `int` value. `i` no longer points to the location of `j`.

```
*i = j;
```

Set the value stored in location pointed to by `i` to have the same value as `j`, in this case 7.

```
j = j + 5;
```

Increment `j` by 5. Since `i` no longer points to `&j` the value stored in `*i` is unaffected.

```
printf("%d %d", *i, j);
```

Print value of `*i` and `j`.
As previously demonstrated `i` points to a memory location holding a value of 7 and `j` is 7 + 5 = 12.